# PHP/MySQL: Show only specific columns within a loop?

Tags: php, mysql, loops

I am programming a voting system where users can upload up to 20 images per project (see attached image). Currently I am displaying per Row the project ID, an image and a text (text is the same in the same project). When the user adds 20 Images to the project the text will be shown 20 times. Now I am trying to rebuild the display part (see the attached Image) - instead of 20 rows, there should only be one row per user and project,[image] but I have no clue how to achieve this. Thank you for your help.

This is my SQL syntax:

```
SELECT * from wp_awa_upload WHERE wp_awa_upload.uid = '$_SESSION[id]' and stat < 3 order by parent_cat, id asc
```

And this is the Part where I print the result of the table:

```
<form method="POST" action="<?php echo $_SERVER["PHP_SELF"]; ?>" enctype="multipart/form-data">
 <? $i = 0; ?>
 <? while ($show = mysql_fetch_array($abfrage)) {   ?>
<form action="" method="POST">
<td><? echo $show['parent_cat'];?><br><input name="uid" type="#hidden" class="style13" value="<?php echo $show['uid']; ?>" id="uid" style="width: 40px" readonly /></td>
<td align="center"><a href="<? echo $show['url']; ?>" data-lightbox="<? echo $show['file_name']; ?>" data-title="<? echo $show['file_name']; ?>"><? echo $show['file_name']; ?><br><div class="center-cropped"><img src="<? echo $show['url'] ?>" border="0"><br></a></div><br>©: <input name="copyright" type="text" class="style13" value="<?php if ($rolle <> '1') {echo $show['copyright'];} ?>" id="copyright" style="width: 140px" /><br><? if ( $show['youtube'] <> '') { echo '<a href="'. $show['youtube'] .'" style="color: #CC0000">Youtube</a>'; }?></td>
<td><textarea name ='project' rows='16' cols='30' style="resize: none;"><?php if ($i == 0) { echo $show['project']; } ?></textarea></td>
<td><textarea name ='testimonial' rows='16' cols='30' style="resize: none;"><?php echo $show['testimonial']; ?></textarea><br>
<? if ($show['parent_cat'] == "Bester Styled Shoot") { ?>Styled Shoot Teilnehmer<br>
<textarea name ='styled' rows='8' cols='30' style="resize: none;"><?php echo $show['styled']; } ?></textarea></td> 
<td><textarea name ='beschreibung' rows='16' cols='30' style="resize: none;"><?php echo $show['beschreibung']; ?></textarea></td>
<td><? if ($rolle <> 1 && $show['stat'] == 0 ) { echo '<button type="submit" value="' . $show['id']. '" name="change">Speichern?</button>'; ?><br><? echo '<button type="submit" value="' . $show['id']. '" name="delete">Löschen?</button>'; } ?></td>
<td><? if ($rolle == '1') { ?>
<select name="rating" class="style28" style="width: 120px" id="rating">
    <option value="0">0</option>
    <option value="5">5</option>
    <option value="15">15</option>
    <option value="20">20</option>
    <option value="25">25</option>
    <option value="30">30</option>   
    <option value="35">35</option>
    <option value="40">40</option>
    <option value="45">45</option>
    <option value="50">50</option>
    <option value="55">55</option>
    <option value="60">60</option>
    <option value="65">65</option>
    <option value="70">70</option>
    <option value="75">75</option>
    <option value="80">80</option>
    <option value="85">85</option>
    <option value="90">90</option>
    <option value="95">95</option>
    <option value="100">100</option>
    </select> <? echo '<button type="submit" value="' . $show['id']. '" name="submit">Bewerten?</button>'; }

    elseif ($rolle == 9) {

        echo '<button type="freigeben" value="' . $show['id']. '" name="freigeben">Freigeben?</button>';
        echo '<button type="verwerfen" value="' . $show['id']. '" name="verwerfen">Verwerfen?</button><br><br>';
        echo '<hr><br>'; ?>
        E-Mail an Kunden schreiben:<br><textarea name ='informed' rows='8' cols='30' style="resize: none;"></textarea><br> 
        <? echo '<button type="informieren" value="' . $show['id']. '" name="informieren">Informieren?</button>'; 



    }?></td>

  </form>
```

I tried with an $i = 0; and then with a "if $i == 0 {} but, this is not working if a user has more than 1 project (the other project will not be displayed)

Thank you for your help!

Kind Regards, Stefan

Comment: please show what you have you have tried

Comment: I think a meaningful answer for you would probably need to know how you plan to HTML format up to 20 images in a single logical row.

Comment: Do you have a single Table ?

Comment: This is simple and can be achieved in many ways. But, we can't assume how your data are being stored in table, how you are retrieving it. You need to show your code, if you seek help/suggestions from our end.

Comment: Dear Tim, Vijay, Nana - Thank you for your time and your feedback. I have to clean up my code before I am able to post it (shame on me for programming "quick and dirty")

Answer (score 0):

I guess you want to display common text for all similar project images and id with It's related id & image.

You can do this by creating sub-array for managing image & id & main array for text description. Whenever same description received it'll break the loop & sub sequent data will be added as sub-array of main array. Try this. Hope it helps

```
$mainArry = array();
        foreach($arrData as $item){     
            $idx = 0;
            foreach($mainArry as $cat){
                if($cat['text_description'] == $item['text_description']){
                    break;
                }
                $idx++;
            }

            $itemArry = array('id'=> ,'images' => );    
            if($idx >= 0){
                $mainArry[$idx]['text_description'] = $item['text_description'];                
                $mainArry[$idx]['items'][] = $itemArry;         
            }   
        }
```

Answer (score 0):

You should be doing a preprocessing of data (data massaging) before you use it for your template.

You can start by grouping rows with similar project

Example:

```
$processed_data = array();
foreach($rows as $row){
   $processed_data[$row["project_id"][] = $row;
}
```

In this way, you can have something like this;

```
[
  1 => [
    [project 1, image1...]
    [project 1, image2...]
    [project 1, image3...]
  ],
  2 => [
    [project 2, image1...]
    [project 2, image2...]  
    .....
  ]
]
```

Then in your template, it will be easier for you to display data with similar group

Answer (score 0):

There are two methods I have mentioned below.

Please note that, these solutions are given based on following assumtions
1. You are using PHP
2. Database field names are userid, prjoject, text, image
3. You have stored imge src in the database.

**Method 1:**

```
SELECT userid, project, 
GROUP_CONCAT(image separator ',') as images_list, 
GROUP_CONCAT(image separator ',') as text_list 
FROM  your_table
GROUP BY userid,project
```

Above query returns data as you expected. Now you just need to populate those data into a html table.

**Method 2:**

Group data by user and project in your php code using a associative array.

$sql = "SELECT * FROM your_table";

Get query result to a PHP associative array. I assume the variable name is $data

```
$result = array();

foreach($data as $row) {
    $userid = $row['userid'];
    $project = $row['project'];
    $result[$userid][$project]['text'][] = array('text' => $row['text'], 'image' => $row['image']);
}
```

**HTML:**

```
<table>
    <?php foreach($result as $key_1 => $projects) { //userid holds $key_1 ?>
        <?php foreach($projects as $key_2 => row ) {?> 
            <tr>
                <td><?php echo $key_1; ?></td>
                <td><?php echo $key_2; ?></td>
                <td>
                    <table>
                        <tr><td><?php echo $row['text']?></td><tr>
                        <tr><td><img src="<?php echo $row['image']?>"></td><tr>
                    </table>
                </td>
            </tr>
        <?php }?>
    <?php } ?>
</table>
```

Following links may be helpful for more understanding.

1. [MySql GROUP_CONCAT](https://www.w3resource.com/mysql/aggregate-functions-and-grouping/aggregate-functions-and-grouping-group_concat.php)
2. [PHP Associative array.](http://php.net/manual/en/language.types.array.php)

Comment: Dear Thusan, thank you for your Feedback. I will give it a try!

Answer (score 0):

Hi thank you for your answers so far. I am nearly at the point where I could say "solved" :-)

```
$sql = "SELECT * from wp_awa_upload where stat = '0' order by parent_cat asc";
if (!$result = $mysqli->query($sql)) {
// Oh no! The query failed. 
echo "Sorry, the website is experiencing problems.";

// Again, do not do this on a public site, but we'll show you how
// to get the error information
echo "Error: Our query failed to execute and here is why: \n";
echo "Query: " . $sql . "\n";
echo "Errno: " . $mysqli->errno . "\n";
echo "Error: " . $mysqli->error . "\n";
exit;
}

 $last_entry = null;


echo "<table width='100%' border='1' align='center'><tr>";

echo "<tr>";

    echo "<td align='center'>Projektnamen</td>";
    echo "<td align='center'>UID</td>";
    echo "<td align='center'>Kategorie</td>";
    echo "<td align='center'>Projektbeschreibung</td>";
    echo "<td align='center'>Beschreibung</td>";
    echo "<td align='center'>Copyright</td>";
    echo "<td align='center'>Tools</td>";


echo "</tr>";


while ($row = $result->fetch_object()) {

echo "<tr>";

if ($last_entry != $row->project) {

echo "<td align='center'><textarea name ='project' rows='16' cols='30'     style='resize: none'>".$row->project."</textarea></td>";
    echo "<td align='center'>".$row->uid."</td>";
    echo "<td align='center'>".$row->parent_cat."</td>";
    echo "<td align='center'><textarea name ='project_desc' rows='16' cols='30' style='resize: none'>".$row->project_desc."</textarea></td>";
    echo "<td align='center'><textarea name ='beschreibung' rows='16' cols='30' style='resize: none'>".$row->beschreibung."</textarea></td>";
    echo "<td align='center'>".$row->copyright."</td>";
    echo "<td align='center'>Buttons</td>";
echo "</tr>";
echo "<tr>"; 
    $last_entry = $row->project;


}

    //echo "<td align='center' colspan='6'><img src=".$row->url."<border='0'>   </td>"; 
    echo "<td align='center' colspan='7'>";
    echo "<a href='".$row->url."' data-lightbox='".$row->file_name."' data-title='".$row->file_name."'><br><div class='center-cropped'><img src='".$row->url."' border='0'></a></div>";

}
echo "</tr>";
echo "</table>";
```

The Description, Category,... will be displayed only once, the images will be displayed, but not side by side - they will be displayed with a line break.

My Question: How can I display the images side by side (4 in a row?) As I could have up to 20 Images in a project, it would be nice to show them in a pack of 4 and a max. of 5 Rows.

Thank you for you help and assistance.

Kind Regards,

Stefan